# how to use 'wget' to download a whole web site 

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget

i use this code to download :

```
wget -m -k -H http://www.digu.com
```

but if some file cant be download , it will retry Again and again ，

so  how to skip this file and download other files ,

thanks

Comment: Doesn't the rsync client tool also work in this space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `--tries` option to wget. With it you can limit the number of retries for a file. See the [wget documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options).